# Laravel 5.4 odbc connection MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server-2008, odbc, laravel-5.4

I need to config Laravel 5.4 to use the ODBC PDO Driver for Microsoft SQL Server.I didnt find any useful resource. If anyone previously used odbc in laravel 5.4 please help me out.

Database.php

```
    'odbc'   => [
        'driver'   => 'odbc',
        'dsn'      => 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=
        {serverName};Trusted_Connection=true;Database=meteor;',
        'host'     => 'DESKTOP-B9M4O7M\SQLEXPRESS',
        'database' => 'meteor',
        'username' => 'DESKTOP-B9M4O7M\admin',
        'password' => '',
        'grammar' => [
            'query' => Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar::class,
            'schema' => Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar::class,
        ],
     ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a couple of settings, and misunderstood a couple of others. Try the following:

```
'odbc'   => [
    /* USE sql server as the driver, and set odbc settings (see below) */
    'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',

    /* Tell laravel that you are using odbc */
    'odbc'     => true,

    /* Set the ODBC data source, your previous dns */
    'odbc_datasource_name' => '{SQL Server}',

    /* There is no dsn config variable that I am aware of */
    /*'dsn'    => 'Driver={SQL Server};Server={serverName};Trusted_Connection=true;Database=meteor;', */

    /* host is the server */
    'host'     => '{serverName}', /*'DESKTOP-B9M4O7M\SQLEXPRESS',*/

    'database' => 'meteor',
    'username' => 'DESKTOP-B9M4O7M\admin',
    'password' => '',
    'grammar' => [
        'query' => Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar::class,
        'schema' => Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar::class,
    ],
 ],
```